# Unittest for C++ running on an AtMega32a

Tags: c++, unit-testing, microcontroller

I've made a workflow to unit test C code for an AtMega32a. I've used a combination of the C test framework "unity"[1] and the AVR simulator "simavr"[2]. After I write the C code, I push it to a Gitlab server. The Gitlab server downloads and runs a docker container, installs gccavr, simavr to it, compiles the C code, and then runs the code in Simavr. Simavr pipes the messages from unity from the serial port to the console. When the tests are complete, the gitlab server sends me an e-mail with the results.

[1] http://www.throwtheswitch.org/unity

[2] https://github.com/buserror/simavr

Now I would like to do the same, but this time with C++ code. I'm therefore looking for a C++ test suite that:

a) Is written in C++, or can be called from C++ code

b) Runs on an AVR

c) Can send it's messages to the serial port. (So I can run the code also in a real AtMega32a connected to a serial port of my PC)

Do you know of such a suite?

Cheers,
Cedric

Answer (score 0):

Google recently released **pigweed**, a framework for embedded development in C++, which includes [unit test functionality](https://pigweed.googlesource.com/pigweed/pigweed/#embedded-testing-for-mcus).

It's platform-agnostic and doesn't require heap allocations, so you'd only need to implement an [Event Handler interface](https://pigweed.googlesource.com/pigweed/pigweed/+/refs/heads/master/pw_unit_test/public/pw_unit_test/event_handler.h) to report your results through something like the serial port. It also includes [a handler example](https://pigweed.googlesource.com/pigweed/pigweed/+/refs/heads/master/pw_unit_test/simple_printing_event_handler.cc), which you can reimplement the `WriteLine` function for your platform.

Now, if I recall correctly, the AVR-GCC doesn't include the C++ Standard Library, which would be a problem, because pigweed requires some Standard Library headers. For that, I recommend taking a look at something like [ETL](https://github.com/ambroise-leclerc/ETL), which should implement most of what you need.